# iOS redirects to the AppStore to fill up billing information. How to return user in the app after filling?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, itunes

I'm faced with issue when iOS redirects to the AppStore app to fill some info in user account during in-app purchasing. But after filling it doesn't return back to the app.

Is there any ways to do that? I didn't find any info about it on developer.apple.com.

I will be glad to hear any ideas how to fix it.

Comment: It should be one-time action, anyway, are you looking for solution of catching this event and how get to your app, that you are developing, or as a user of it?

Comment: I'm looking for solution of catching this event as developer. I just want to make app as user-friendly as possible =) Because some user told me that during purchases they're staying in strange place. I guess that "that place" is strange.

Comment: From iOS 9.0, there is kinda shortcut link in the top left corner of the status bar, I hope people are familiar with it enough, but I don't think there is another possibility to get users back to your (to any) app, if App Store isn't just redirecting back.

Comment: @pedrouan Yeah, absolutely agree with. I thought in same direction about back icon.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in the app (or in the system feature controller) that you haven't any impact on, it's impossible to make any hint or direction anywhere.

This appears to be Apple's business only, even if is not nice to stuck on billing view at all.

My suggestion - to get people back to your app - could be `Local Notification`, that could be registered as soon as you catch certain event, like this:

**1.** You will know, what action (touch event etc.) could direct them to billing info view, so you may need to create some delegate method or a selector, that will register a notification right before user's action in your controller is redirecting them to billing view

**2.** Your user is now in the billing info and you can raise a local notification, for example after 25 seconds, you will ask them for instance:

**a)** "If you are ready to your app billing info, tap here"

or

**b)** "Once you are ready with an billing information, press home button twice and get to XYZ app."